# prettyPhoto: make popup window bigger than default

Tags: javascript

How I can set popup window size bigger than normal?

http://d.pr/Md3E+

There is too many space at the top and the bottom of the description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the width and height in as parameters. So your constructor may look like this:

```
$("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({
    default_width: 500,
    default_height: 344
});
```

You can see the full list of options [here](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/documentation/)

Comment: Thank you Shane, also thank for the docu link. Set default_width _height is not the best, because everyone have different resolution. What is in that case, when I set to high width and height? The best would be an resolution-dependent _width _height option.

Comment: @Adrian, How you fixed it based on screen resolution? I'm also having same issue.

Comment: @MansoorkhanCherupuzha Sorry, I don't remember. I am not using prettyPhoto anymore.